# angular material 13 - checkbox checked property is checked when set to 0

Tags: angular, angular-material

After upgrading from Angular 12 to 13, I noticed that when the checked property for a checkbox is set to 0, the checkbox is checked.

But, it is unchecked when set to false.

So, 0 and false behaved the same in version 12, appearing as unchecked, but differently in version 13.

In this example, workOrderDtiConstraint.ESCALATED is the field used.  When set to 0, the box is checked, when set to false, it is unchecked.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="escalated">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Escalated</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="checkBox" *matCellDef="let workOrderDtiConstraint, let i = index">
      <mat-checkbox color="primary"
         [checked]="workOrderDtiConstraint.ESCALATED">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper function like this:

```
getBoolean(value) {
    switch (value) {
        case true:
        case "true":
        case "True":
        case 1:
        case "1":
        case "on":
        case "yes":
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

And your code would be like this:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="escalated">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Escalated</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell class="checkBox" *matCellDef="let workOrderDtiConstraint, let i = index">
      <mat-checkbox color="primary"
         [checked]="getBoolean(workOrderDtiConstraint.ESCALATED)">
      </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks - Are you aware of the change behavior from version 12 to 13?

Comment: Looking at the `coerceBooleanProperty` tests, it looks like this is intended behavior: https://github.com/angular/components/blob/main/src/cdk/coercion/boolean-property.spec.ts

Comment: This is the commit in which it happened: https://github.com/angular/components/commit/1e9092a5b71f7dc0932dcce8479c3e43cbed24e9. There's already a comment on it from someone having this exact issue

Comment: Because this change was made by the Angular team and isn't a bug, I updated my app to convert 1 and 0 to true and false before setting the checked property - Thanks for everyone's help